# Node.Js (Sails.js) App Crashing Right After Launch - Process Out of Memory: How do I debug?

Tags: node.js, memory, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, sails.js

I've been developing an app with Sails.js (an framework for Node.js) and it's been mostly working well on both my local environment and on AWS.  Recently, though, one of the servers has crashed with a "Process Out of Memory" error. In fact, the one server now crashes within a second of running `npm start`.  I've temporarily fixed this issue before by making an image of the server and launching it as a new instance on a larger server, but an immediate crash like this isn't just a matter of needing extra space.

I assume my code has caused a memory leak, but I'm having trouble finding any clues to identify the source of the problem.  **What are the best tools to debug memory allocation issues in Node.js apps?**

*Edit:* I'm aware of [the `-inspect` flag](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/) and I'm poking around with that, but I'm specifically curious of how I might monitor the memory of my app as it runs on a remote server.

Here's the error output from the crashed server, if that's any help.  It was running on a t2.large EC2 instance with Node v8.1.2 and npm v5.6.0.

```
[34mdebug: [39mhookPath: /home/bitnami/emotics-sails-api/node_modules/sails-auth/dist/api/hooks/auth
[34mdebug: [39mmarlinspike (auth): loading config from /home/bitnami/emotics-sails-api/node_modules/sails-auth/dist/config
[34mdebug: [39mmarlinspike (auth): loading Services from /home/bitnami/emotics-sails-api/node_modules/sails-auth/dist/api/services...
[34mdebug: [39mmarlinspike (auth): loading Models...
[34mdebug: [39mmarlinspike (auth): loading Controllers...
[34mdebug: [39mmarlinspike (auth): loading Policies...
[34mdebug: [39m-------------------------------------------------------
[34mdebug: [39m:: Wed Feb 28 2018 05:18:29 GMT+0000 (UTC)
[34mdebug: [39mEnvironment : development
[34mdebug: [39mPort        : 80
[34mdebug: [39m-------------------------------------------------------
[31merror: [39mGrunt :: FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [grunt]
 2: 0x13647ec [grunt]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [grunt]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [grunt]
 5: 0xa9686b [grunt]
 6: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceAndCandidates() [grunt]
 7: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [grunt]
 8: v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [grunt]
 9: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [grunt]
10: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [grunt]
11: v8::internal::Factory::NewWeakCell(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>) [grunt]
12: v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo::SetScript(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [grunt]
13: v8::internal::Factory::NewSharedFunctionInfoForLiteral(v8::internal::FunctionLiteral*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Script>) [grunt]
14: v8::internal::Compiler::GetSharedFunctionInfo(v8::internal::FunctionLiteral*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Script>, v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [grunt]
15: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::VisitFunctionLiteral(v8::internal::FunctionLiteral*) [grunt]
16: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::VisitForAccumulatorValue(v8::internal::Expression*) [grunt]
17: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::VisitAssignment(v8::internal::Assignment*) [grunt]
18: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::VisitExpressionStatement(v8::internal::ExpressionStatement*) [grunt]
19: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::Generate() [grunt]
20: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::MakeCode(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*, unsigned long) [grunt]
21: v8::internal::FullCodegenCompilationJob::ExecuteJobImpl() [grunt]
22: v8::internal::CompilationJob::ExecuteJob() [grunt]
23: 0xd97d90 [grunt]
24: 0xd98b28 [grunt]
25: 0xd98d8f [grunt]
26: 0xd9ce59 [grunt]
27: v8::internal::Compiler::Compile(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ClearExceptionFlag) [grunt]
28: v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [grunt]
29: 0xcf123c0437d
```

I tried updating npm, but that ran out of memory as well.  Is there a way to clear up memory in the CLI?  Might there be a process running that I'm not aware of?

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-##-##:~/my-project$ sudo npm i -g npm
Error: could not get uid/gid
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 2: 0x13647ec [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 5: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 6: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 7: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 8: v8::internal::Factory::NewConsString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 9: v8::internal::AstValueFactory::Internalize(v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
10: 0xd99742 [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
11: v8::internal::Compiler::GetSharedFunctionInfoForScript(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, int, v8::ScriptOriginOptions, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Context>, v8::Extension*, v8::internal::ScriptData**, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions, v8::internal::NativesFlag) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
12: v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnboundInternal(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
13: v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnboundScript(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
14: 0x1393897 [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
15: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
16: 0xb43b3b [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
17: v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
18: 0x21e4b490437d

    at /opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js:37:16
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:277:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:897:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:17)
    at /opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:83:20
    at cb (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:224:22)
    at /opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:262:24
    at /opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:80:13
    at f (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:178:20)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:236:22)
    at /opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js:39:14
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:277:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:897:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:329:26)
```

Comment: Lots of flags from grunt... any recent changes to how styles, scripts, etc are compiled? The task `grunt watch` could probably get itself into an infinite loop if it's watching files for changes, then changing them as a result.

Comment: I don't believe so, but that's a good lead. Sails.J's had a default gruntfile that I haven't touched much. Would it make sense to disable watch and see if that helps?

Comment: I'd say yes... if you can disable some grunt task (starting with `watch`) and it fixes the problem, then you know it will be worth your time to dig into grunt and see what's going on. If you end up needing to dig into it and aren't familiar with grunt, I found a this a great help: https://github.com/irlnathan/s-grunt-docs/blob/master/overview.md

Comment: The thing is, I get also errors when I run `npm i -g npm` (see edit, above).  That couldn't be related to grunt, right?